# Does celery.conf.update propagate changes to all workers?

Tags: flask, celery, celerybeat

I'm using the following to add new scheduled tasks to Celery:

```
# tasks.py

@celery.task(name='update_scheduled_tasks')
def update_scheduled_tasks(self):
    existing_celery_tasks = celery.conf['CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER']
    new_celery_tasks = load_more_tasks(existing_celery_tasks)
    celery.conf.update(CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER=new_celery_tasks)
```

And then I call the task `update_scheduled_tasks` when a new task is added:

```
celery.tasks['update_scheduled_tasks].delay()
```

This works fine with one Celery worker; it gets the new scheduled tasks added to it. Will it work the same even if I have multiple workers? How does Celery propagate config changes to multiple workers? I couldn't find anything in the docs about this.

PS I'm using Flask, so `django-celery` isn't an option for me.

Comment: Did you ever figure out an answer to this? Also, is your load_more_tasks() function a custom JSON concatenating function or something else?

Comment: I still don't know the answer for sure. Instead, I settled for adding new task configs to a database (along with their schedules), running a single task that runs every hour, reads task configs out of the DB and runs the ones that need to be run (crappy, I know). In my opinion, workers getting changes automatically isn't possible; my workers certainly didn't update on their own. `load_more_tasks` was a function that added more things to the `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` object.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - for now, I'm just using apply_async(ETA = ) that I assign using a database...